# Why there is "Skip Navigation Links" for my SiteMapPath in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

I have a site map in top of my master page , When i run in Firefox the first node is "Skip Navigation Links"  What's that ? And How can i get rid of that ? It's noticeable that that's not in IE .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Skip Navigation is there for accessibility purposes. If it's part of an ASP.NET Menu, and you want to disable it, try setting the attribute:

`SkipLinkText=""`

See [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/976796/3212427.aspx#3212427) for details on SkipLink and Menus.

Comment: There are two, one at the beginning and one at the end. How do I hide the beginning one and show the last one?